# in Emacs flyspell-mode, how to add new word to dictionary?

Tags: emacs, aquamacs, flyspell, ispell

In Aquamacs in flyspell-mode, when flyspell flags a word as misspelled, I can right-click to add the word to my dictionary if it is in fact correctly spelled.

In GNU Emacs on OSX, when flyspell-mode highlights a word it thinks is misspelled, how can I add the word to the dictionary? Looking at the documentation, I do not see a function like `flyspell-learn-word` or `ispell-add-word-to-personal-dictionary`.

Comment: Is the function `flyspell-correct-word-before-point` defined, try calling it with (`C-c $`) with point on the incorrect word, it gives an option to save the word.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without navigating through a drop-down menu?

Comment: Is there a way to add a compound like "half-hearted" ? Only "hearted" gets the wiggly red underline and flyspell tries to add "hearted" to the dictionary.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The function you are looking for is `flyspell-correct-word-before-point`. By default it is bound to the keys <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>$</kbd>. Move your point to the incorrect word and execute the command. You will get a popup-menu with possible corrections and an option to save the word to you dictionary.

If you want a single command to save the current word, this is what I was able to extract from flyspell.el

```lisp
(defun my-save-word ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((current-location (point))
         (word (flyspell-get-word)))
    (when (consp word)    
      (flyspell-do-correct 'save nil (car word) current-location (cadr word) (caddr word) current-location))))
```

Comment: But where is the new word saved to?

Comment: @strongwillow, in `~/.aspell.LANG.pws`, for aspell or `~/.ispell_DICTNAME` for ispell. See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17237/in-emacs-where-is-ispells-personal-dictionary-stored

Answer (score 18):

You can probably use `M-$` to open suggestions, then `i` to save to dictionary. You'd be prompted for confirmation.

[Source](https://superuser.com/questions/419017/flyspell-save-word-to-dictionary)

Comment: that's three steps, whereas the accepted solution above is one step

Comment: to avoid confirmation and just save it: `(setq ispell-silently-savep t)`